# How to set the path to images in ckeditor?

Tags: wysiwyg, input-formats

I have a recurrent problem I can't solve.

when working in localhost I use ckeditor to upload images to the body field. These images are shown correctly.

Then after, I upload the site to the remote host and all those images links are broken.

The problem is that the drupal installation on my localhost is inside a folder in localhost like: `http://localhost/mysite.com/`

In the remote host all the images links have the `mysite.com`part of the url which of course is wrong. This is not solved by clearing caches.

**Localhost** (works fine)

`http://localhost/mysite.com/sites/default/files/resize/icon-questions-180x127.png`

**Remote** (with the wrong "mysite.com")

`http://mysite.dde.oneserver.com/mysite.com/sites/default/files/resize/icon-questions-180x127.png`

With no luck I tried with several configurations at: **admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full**

**UPDATE (trying with Pathologic module)**
I added these lines in "All base paths for this site" in Pathologic setting at `admin/config/content/formats/full_html`:

```
http://localhost/mysite.com/ (this one is where the site was developed)
http://mysite.dde.oneserver.com (this one is where the site lives now)
```

I ALSO tried adding:

`http://mysite.dde.oneserver.com/mysite.com`

look the capture:
[image]

Comment: What does the actual path in the field look like? Is it `/mysite.com/sites/default/files…` ? If so, try putting `/mysite.com/` in the "All base paths for this site" field.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try [Pathologic](http://drupal.org/project/pathologic) module to see if that works for you.

> Pathologic is an input filter which can correct paths in links and images in your Drupal content in situations which would otherwise cause them to “break;” for example, if the URL of the site changes, or the content was moved to a different server. Pathologic can also solve the problem of missing images and broken links in your site’s RSS feeds.

Comment: I have pathologic enabled. I'll try it.

Comment: I can't get it working, could you take a look at my update at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 0):

May be there was a configuration missing! Have you ever try the following way to resolve the problem? I think it might be a good choice for you (this CKEditor add-on will automatically calculate correct URL for your images: in my projects I leave in not configured and it successfully understands what URL prefix must be used):

http://doksoft.com/soft/ckutils/bundle-install.html